# Converting SQL into LINQ To SQL statement

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

Can someone please help convert the following into LINQ To SQL query?

```
select * from projects pr
where pr.Active<>0 
AND CapturedDocumentType=2 
AND SubmissionReminderTypeID > 0 
AND pr.ProjectID In(SELECT Max(wpr.ProjectID) as ProjID 
                    FROM Projects wpr 
                    where wpr.Active<>0 
                    AND wpr.CapturedDocumentType=2 
                    AND wpr.SubmissionReminderTypeID > 0
                    group by wpr.EmployeeID)
```

Comment: in this query you dont need the first 3 where conditions. you are already checking for that in your nested query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var result = from pr in dc.Projects
             where 
                (from wpr in dc.Projects
                 where wpr.Active && 
                       wpr.CapturedDocumentType == 2 && 
                       wpr.SubmissionReminderTyepID > 0
                 group wpr by wpr.EmployeeID into gpr
                 select gpr.Max(x => x.ProjectID)).Contains(pr.ProjectID)
             select pr;
```

Comment: I'm getting ProjectID does not exist in context in this part gpr.Max(ProjectID).

Comment: lets try `select Max(gpr.ProjectID)` instead.
I'll try in Visual Studio today